# Mystery of "this" in ReactJS

Tags: facebook, reactjs, react-native, react-router

I am fairly new to the Facebook's React world.  Their documentation seems to be very good but there are a few areas where I need a little bit of clarity.  This is one of them.

Src: http://tuts-javascript.appspot.com/reactjs-add-remove-table-row

```
    var CompanyApp = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
      return {companylist:this.props.companies};
    },
    handleNewRowSubmit: function( newcompany ) {
      this.setState( {companylist: this.state.companylist.concat([newcompany])} );
    },
    handleCompanyRemove: function( company ) {
      
      var index = -1;   
      var clength = this.state.companylist.length;
        for( var i = 0; i < clength; i++ ) {
            if( this.state.companylist[i].cname === company.cname ) {
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        this.state.companylist.splice( index, 1 );  
        this.setState( {companylist: this.state.companylist} );
    },
    render: function() {
      var tableStyle = {width: '100%'};
      var leftTdStyle = {width: '50%',padding:'20px',verticalAlign: 'top'};
      var rightTdStyle = {width: '50%',padding:'20px',verticalAlign: 'top'};
      return ( 
        <table style={tableStyle}>
          <tr>
            <td style={leftTdStyle}>
              <CompanyList clist={this.state.companylist}  onCompanyRemove={this.handleCompanyRemove}/>
            </td>
            <td style={rightTdStyle}>
              <NewRow onRowSubmit={this.handleNewRowSubmit}/>
            </td>
          </tr>
      </table>
      );
    }
  });
  
  var CompanyList = React.createClass({
    handleCompanyRemove: function(company){
      this.props.onCompanyRemove( company );
    },
    render: function() {
      var companies = [];
      var that = this; // TODO: Needs to find out why that = this made it work; Was getting error that onCompanyDelete is not undefined
      this.props.clist.forEach(function(company) {
        companies.push(<Company company={company} onCompanyDelete={that.handleCompanyRemove} /> );
      });
      return ( 
        <div>
          <h3>List of Companies</h3>
          <table className="table table-striped">
            <thead><tr><th>Company Name</th><th>Employees</th><th>Head Office</th><th>Action</th></tr></thead>
            <tbody>{companies}</tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        );
    }
  });
  
  var Company = React.createClass({
    handleRemoveCompany: function() {
      this.props.onCompanyDelete( this.props.company );
      return false;
    },
    render: function() {
      return (
        <tr>
          <td>{this.props.company.cname}</td>
          <td>{this.props.company.ecount}</td>
          <td>{this.props.company.hoffice}</td>
          <td><input type="button"  className="btn btn-primary" value="Remove" onClick={this.handleRemoveCompany}/></td>
        </tr>
        );
    }
  });
  
  var NewRow = React.createClass({
    handleSubmit: function() {
      var cname = this.refs.cname.getDOMNode().value;
      var ecount = this.refs.ecount.getDOMNode().value;
      var hoffice = this.refs.hoffice.getDOMNode().value;
      var newrow = {cname: cname, ecount: ecount, hoffice: hoffice };
      this.props.onRowSubmit( newrow );
      
      this.refs.cname.getDOMNode().value = '';
      this.refs.ecount.getDOMNode().value = '';
      this.refs.hoffice.getDOMNode().value = '';
      return false;
    },
    render: function() {
      var inputStyle = {padding:'12px'}
      return ( 
        <div className="well">
          <h3>Add A Company</h3>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <div className="input-group input-group-lg" style={inputStyle}>
            <input type="text"  className="form-control col-md-8"  placeholder="Company Name" ref="cname"/>
          </div>
          <div className="input-group input-group-lg" style={inputStyle}>
            <input type="text"  className="form-control col-md-8" placeholder="Employee Count" ref="ecount"/>
          </div>
          <div className="input-group input-group-lg" style={inputStyle}>
            <input type="text"  className="form-control col-md-8" placeholder="Headoffice" ref="hoffice"/>
          </div>
          <div className="input-group input-group-lg" style={inputStyle}>
            <input type="submit"  className="btn btn-primary" value="Add Company"/>
          </div>
        </form>
        </div>
        );
    }
  });
  var defCompanies = [{cname:"Infosys Technologies",ecount:150000,hoffice:"Bangalore"},{cname:"TCS",ecount:140000,hoffice:"Mumbai"}];
  React.renderComponent( <CompanyApp companies={defCompanies}/>, document.getElementById( "companyApp" ) );
```

This is a very good basic explanation of how ReactJS works.  Thanks to the author.

But this comment,

> var that = this; // TODO: Needs to find out why that = this made it work; Was getting error that onCompanyDelete is not undefined

Why is that necessary?
Is this the right way to do it? If not, what is?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not really related to React, it's basic JS. I'd recommend googling for "javascript context"

Comment: it is not neccessary anymore, and it is not the right way to do it. in short :)

Comment: @luschn.. why would you say "it is not necessary anymore"?

Comment: because we have ES6 now. it was just a workaround a long time ago. read about arrow functions (and ES6 in general).

Comment: as ivarni mentioned, that's not a react thing, it is javascript basics. if you do not know about ES6 yet, you should really learn it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's no mystery of "this" that is specific to ReactJS.

This is just a case of standard scoping issues that crop up with callbacks in JavaScript.

When you're in a react component, all methods on the base component will be scoped with the `this` being the current component, just like any other JavaScript "class".

In your snippet you have a `render` method which is a function on the base component and therefore `this` is equal to the component itself.  However within that render method you're calling a callback with `this.props.clist.forEach`, any function callbacks inside the `render` method will need to be either bound to the correct `this` scope, or you can do `var that = this` (although this is an anti-pattern and should be discouraged)`.

Example, slightly simplified version of your snippet:

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
    handleCompanyRemove: function(e) {
        // ...
    },
    render: function() {
        // this === MyComponent within this scope

        this.props.someArray.forEach(function(item) {
            // this !== MyComponent, therefore this.handleCompanyRemove cannot
            // be called!
        })
    }
})
```

As you can see from the comments above, inside your callback for the `.forEach` you cannot use `this` directly without either defining a variable outside, or properly binding the function.

Other options to solve this are:

**Binding** the callback function to the correct this scope.  Example:

```
this.props.someArray.forEach(function(item) {
    // this === MyComponent within this scope too now!
    // so you can call this.handleCompanyRemove with no problem
 }.bind(this))
```

If you're using Babel/ES6 you can use the **Fat Arrow** function syntax which guarantees that `this` scope continues to the callback from the parent scope.  Example:

```
this.props.someArray.forEach((item) => {
    // this === MyComponent within this scope too now!
    // so you can call this.handleCompanyRemove with no problem
})
```

Comment: According to MDN, you can also give `forEach` a context for `this`. e.g `this.props.someArray.forEach(function(item) { }, this)` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: Indeed, but that's specific to forEach - I was trying to be generic to all callbacks but used forEach as it was used by OP in his example.

Comment: @MikeDriver.. thanks a bunch for the answer.  Since you say var that = this should be discouraged, is there any scenario where you think this could cause a problem?

Comment: @Sachin No it'll run fine.  The main reason (for me) why that = this should be discouraged is code readability, it's much nicer just to make sure all your callbacks are properly scoped and to just use `this` all the time.  Certainly if your'e already using babel to transpile your JSX -> JS, es6 fat arrow functions are are the most elegant solution.

Comment: @MikeDriver.. I am infact using babel, lame how the fat arrow function never crossed my mind in such a scenario.  Thanks again for pointing it out.