# What do this() method refers to?

Tags: reactjs, class, this

Can you give an explanation on what do the this() method refers to in Square class and do you have any tips to learn about it more?

I know that It has different values depending on where it is used:

In a method, this refers to the owner object.
Alone, this refers to the global object.
In a function, this refers to the global object.
In a function, in strict mode, this is undefined.
In an event, this refers to the element that received the event.
What is the case here, I am guessing that the this method is called under the render() method so i will get the owner object which is Square in our case. am i right?

```
class Square extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button className="square">
        {this.props.value}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

class Board extends React.Component {
  renderSquare(i) {
    return <Square value={i} />;
  }

  render() {
    const status = 'Next player: X';

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="status">{status}</div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(0)}
          {this.renderSquare(1)}
          {this.renderSquare(2)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(3)}
          {this.renderSquare(4)}
          {this.renderSquare(5)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(6)}
          {this.renderSquare(7)}
          {this.renderSquare(8)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mystery of "this" in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37182461/mystery-of-this-in-reactjs)

Comment: Honestly my advice is to rewrite these as function components and not use `this` at all.  I think it makes it easier to understand.  But `this` in the `Square` refers to that instance of the `Square` component.  `this.props.value` gives you whatever you set as the `value` prop on the component.  Which is the `i` from here: `<Square value={i} />`.  Each of the squares has it's own `this` with its own props.